# different desktop and mobile navbars

Tags: html, css

I would to have a different desktop and mobile menu layout. My desktop menu uses dropdowns, but I would like to mobile menu to just be a vertical list without the dropdowns. I have tried creating a desktop version and a mobile version in the hope I could switch between the two, but that's where I am stuck. How do I achieve this in the CSS? - if that's the right place to do it.

desktop menu

```css
Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
 .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}
/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;

    }

}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  } 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav_desktop" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">History
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ></i>
         </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="history.php">BSAOC</a>
            <a href="bsa.php">BSA Factory</a>
            <a href="the_star.php">The Star</a>
         </div>
 </div>
 <a href="the_star.php">The Star</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Club Services
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ></i>
         </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="membership.php">Membership</a>
            <a href="machine_dating.php">Machine Dating</a>
   <a href="memberarea.php">Members Area</a>
   <a href="forum.php">Forum</a>
   <a href="links.php">Links</a>
   </div>
 </div>
  <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="memberarea.php" style="float:right">Login</a>
  <a h<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

Mobile menu

<div class="topnav_mobile" id="Topnav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="history.php">BSAOC</a>
  <a href="bsa.php">BSA Factory</a>
  <a href="the_star.php">The Star</a>
  <a href="the_star.php">The Star</a>
  <a href="membership.php">Membership</a>
  <a href="machine_dating.php">Machine Dating</a>
  <a href="memberarea.php">Members Area</a>
  <a href="forum.php">Forum</a>
  <a href="links.php">Links</a>
  <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="memberarea.php" style="float:right">Login</a>
  <a h<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: add div#Topnav {display: flex;flex-direction: column;} if that what you need tell me ty

Answer (score 0):

Add below **CSS** in your stylesheet will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.topnav_mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .topnav_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav_mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```